# Drupal 7 - Extract posts and user names

Tags: database

New at Drupal. Trying to extract from MySql the list of the posts with body and user name. Apparently since Drupal 7, the content is stored in drupal_field_data_body. The problem is that it does not contain any user_id, so I have no clue how to join the two tables.
So far I am here:

```
SELECT *
FROM drupal_node node, drupal_node_revision revision, drupal_users users
WHERE 1=1 AND revision.vid=node.vid AND revision.nid=node.nid AND users.uid=node.uid
```

Need to JOIN **drupal_field_data_body**

Comment: No Problems.. just found the solution we can join entity_id with node_id

So:

SELECT users.name , node.title ,  LEFT(FROM_UNIXTIME(node.created),10) date , fdb.body_value 
FROM drupal_node node, drupal_users users , `drupal_users_roles` roles , drupal_field_data_body fdb
WHERE 1=1
AND users.uid=node.uid
and roles.uid=users.uid
and roles.rid=4
and node.nid=fdb.entity_id

Comment: If you found a solution, please post it as an _answer_ to your question and mark it accepted :)

Comment: Could I ask what this query is for? Are you trying to build a custom module, working on a theme, etc.? Depending on the situation, way better solutions might exist like Views: see wiifm's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Can I ask why you are not using [views](https://drupal.org/project/views) for this task?

Views 3 for drupal 7 is a powerful interactive SQL builder. And trivial tasks like this are can be easily sold without even knowing SQL or which tables to join on etc.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of queries, you should use the [EntityFieldQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) class that allows to execute queries for all the entities defined in Drupal 7, and from third-party modules.